# denied: requested access to the resource is denied when pushing image to gitlab registry

Tags: docker, gitlab, registry, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to push an image to gitlab registry.

I've done it many times, so I wonder why I get this error.

I build the image with latest tag:

```
Successfully tagged registry.gitlab.com/mycompany/rgpd_api:latest
```

Then I login and I push:

```
docker login registry.gitlab.com -u gitlab+deploy-token-91931 
docker push registry.gitlab.com/mycompany/rgpd_api:latest
```

But I get:

```
The push refers to repository [registry.gitlab.com/mycompany/rgpd_api]
be679cc302b9: Preparing 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I gave `gitlab+deploy-token-91931` token both `read_repository` and `read_registry` rights.

My repo is:

```
https://gitlab.com/mycompany/rgpd_api
```

I checked with docs page: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/container_registry.html

But when I do it through Gitlab CI, with `gitlab-ci-token`

I can push it normally.

I also tried to regenerate a new token, but still same issue.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: I think the docker login is not right, you can get your correct url from `Packages > Container Registry`

Comment: and for -u to work you need -p

Comment: Yep, I checked the url is OK.

Comment: Also, when you dont put -p, it will ask your passwork interactively

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Yes, I will post the answer after lunch time :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've stumbled upon this question as well and it turns out that

- Group level Deploy tokens can be used to push images to group level container registry similarly to a PAT token with API access or other applicable scopes.
- The image **must** to be tagged with the tag that matches an **existing** project within the group.
- Any image tagged differently will be rejected with the `denied: requested access to the resource is denied` error message.

So, with the setup below:

- GitLab group called `mytest`
- Project within that group called `hello-world`
- Docker image tagged as `registry.gitlab.com/mytest/hello-world`
- Deploy token created for an entire group
- Docker daemon authorized to push to that registry by `cat "<deploy_token>" | docker login -u "<token_username>" --password-stdin registry.gitlab.com`

You will get the following results:

- Successful push for `docker push registry.gitlab.com/mytest/hello-world` because such project exists within the group
- `denied: requested access to the resource is denied` if you try to push an image tagged with the name of the project that does not exist in the group like `docker push registry.gitlab.com/mytest/no-project`

So, again, image must be tagged to match an existing path within te group, like an existing project within the group or a subgroup.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day. When I create a new tag "resource denied" problems are solved.

Comment: very nice, tons of thanks

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? I'm also finding that the tag suffix (part after :) also has to match a branch in the project. So -t <project-name>:<project-branch> seems to be the only thing allowed.

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/index.html#naming-convention-for-your-container-images is the doc. 

The path it provides as an example is the minimum path, you can be more specific if you wish.

<registry server>/<namespace>/<project>[/<optional path>]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have proper configuration in settings.

Go to Settings of project, then "Visibility, project features, permissions" and check "Container registry : Every project can have its own space to store its Docker images" (for members only or for everyone, up to you). Otherwise, the push and pull will be denied.

This happened to me and that's how I solved it.

Answer (score 1):

My error was to use a deploy token to push a image to a registry.

A deploy token can be used to pull an image, but not push it.

So, instead, you can generate a Personal Access Token. You should add at least permissions:

```
read_registry, write_registry
```

Comment: Citation for this? I have the same problem and if what you say is true this is a major WTF as you can add a write_registry scope to the group deploy token.

Comment: This is not correct. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/authenticate_with_container_registry.html

Comment: That's not correct. Deploy tokens work fine to push images

Comment: When creating a Deploy Token with `write_registry` it fails a docker push every time.  But create a Deploy Token with `read_registry` AND `write_registry` and it works fine??  See this link (from above comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/authenticate_with_container_registry.html) which reads ```All of these authentication methods require the minimum scope:

For read (pull) access, to be read_registry.
For write (push) access, to be write_registry and read_registry.```

Answer (score 1):

you can make `docker logout your registry` and login again.
It's recreate your token.
this work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The token permission requires BOTH `write_registry` AND `read_registry`.
Even though the documentation for write_package_registry says "Allows read, write and delete access to the package registry."...

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing in the solution from my recent experience:

If you're using `sudo docker push` it's possible/likely that it's not using your saved credentials, but rather trying to authenticate with non-existent `root` user credentials on your machine.

Try the push with `docker push` instead and see if it's successful.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wasn't aware of the following restriction in the Gitlab [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/index.html#naming-convention-for-your-container-images), relating to the Gitlab image name structure:

"You can append additional names to the end of a container image name, ***up to two levels deep***"

My original image name was ***three*** levels deep under the group and project names, eg:

`<registry server>/<namespace>/<project>/my/image/name:<tag>`

When pushing this image name to my Gitlab image registry, the Docker CLI aborted part way through its 'preparing' stage with error message `denied: requested access to the resource is denied`.

After finding the above guidance in the Gitlab documentation I shortened the image name to `<registry server>/<namespace>/<project>/my/name:<tag>` and was able to successfully push the image.

A confusing trap for the unwary, because the original three-level image name had pushed successfully to a private Docker registry.