# GitLab Registry: Can push a Docker image to one repo, but not another

Tags: gitlab, registry

<sub>Note: This is cross-posted from https://forum.gitlab.com/t/docker-image-can-be-pushed-to-one-repo-but-not-another/76199</sub>

I a project called `foo`, and I have two GitLab groups with different names, let's call them `main` and `customer`:

- `main/foo/`
- `customer/foo/`

I want to build Docker images and push them to the repository using, e.g., `main/foo/foo:latest`, but I also want to push customer-specific builds to the other repository, e.g. `customer/foo/foo:latest`.

I can build and tag an image using the following tag:

```
registry.example.com/main/foo/foo:latest
```

Using `docker buildx`, this is what I see in the end:

```
 => => pushing layers
 => => pushing manifest for registry.example.com/main/foo/foo:latest@sha256:3e6bdc2e8f24d0553d66eeab4f32e532c99034fd6a098c74799d7ff7192d618a
 => => pushing manifest for registry.example.com/main/foo/foo:v1.0.17@sha256:3e6bdc2e8f24d0553d66eeab4f32e532c99034fd6a098c74799d7ff7192d618a
 => [auth] main/foo/foo:pull,push token for registry.example.com
```

Now, when I instead instruct `docker buildx` to build and push an image for `customer/foo/foo:latest`, I get this output in the end:

```
 => => pushing layers
 => [auth] customer/foo/foo:pull,push token for registry.example.com
 => [auth] customer/foo/foo:pull,push token for registry.example.com
 => [auth] customer/foo/foo:pull,push token for registry.example.com
 => [auth] main/foo/foo:pull customer/foo/foo:pull,push token for registry.example.com
 => [auth] customer/foo/foo:pull,push token for registry.example.com
 => [auth] customer/foo/foo:pull,push token for registry.example.com
 => [auth] main/foo/foo:pull customer/foo/foo:pull,push token for registry.example.com
------
 > exporting to image:
------
ERROR: failed to solve: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

To push, I am using a private token with read/write registry scope that is not tied to any particular project (I created it in my user account).

Why can't I push the image with another tag? Curiously, I see the `main/foo/foo:pull` reference in the second build step despite me not ever specifying the `main` part during this build. I am essentially doing:

```bash
docker buildx create --name mybuilder --driver docker-container --bootstrap --use

docker buildx build \
  --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 \
  --push \
  -t "${REGISTRY}/${REGISTRY_IMAGE_PREFIX}/${imageNameLatest}" \
  .
```

Where `REGISTRY_IMAGE_PREFIX` is either `main/foo` or `customer/foo`.

Any ideas?

---

I can boil down the problem to:

```
$ docker pull hello-world:latest                                                                             
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
7050e35b49f5: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:18a657d0cc1c7d0678a3fbea8b7eb4918bba25968d3e1b0adebfa71caddbc346
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest
docker.io/library/hello-world:latest
$ docker tag hello-world:latest registry.example.com/main/foo/foo:latest
$ docker push registry.example.com/main/foo/foo:latest
The push refers to repository [registry.example.com/main/foo/foo]
efb53921da33: Layer already exists 
foo: digest: sha256:432f982638b3aefab73cc58ab28f5c16e96fdb504e8c134fc58dff4bae8bf338 size: 525
$ docker tag hello-world:latest registry.example.com/customer/foo/foo:latest
$ docker push registry.example.com/customer/foo/foo:latest
The push refers to repository [registry.example.com/customer/foo/foo]
efb53921da33: Preparing 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. The project **must** have the *Repository* feature enabled.

[image]

If this is unchecked, you cannot push images for whatever reason, leading to the "requested access to the resource is denied" error.

Note that the error might appear in other cases, too, in which case this answer was very helpful: [denied: requested access to the resource is denied when pushing image to gitlab registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57654620/denied-requested-access-to-the-resource-is-denied-when-pushing-image-to-gitlab)

Comment: Very confusing that this isn't included in the documentation. Thank you so much for finding this!